# Server doesn't bind to client

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock

I am coding in C++ and I need to send data (text) from a server (a Raspberry Pi 4) to a client (my computer).

After a lot of research, I have built a code that is close to the ones available on the Internet. However, when compiling and debugging the `server.cpp` and `client.cpp` files, although there are no apparent errors, sending data from the client to the server and from the server to the client fails.

Indeed, for the client file, I get the error 10060, which is actually understandable since the server could not link with it.

So, I understand that the problem is with my server file (more precisely, with the `bind()` function). But surprisingly, when I use the `perror()` function to check what type of error I am dealing with, I get `"No error"`. I've been trying to figure out why, but so far it's still not clear to me. I have a theory that the problem may be with my IP address or the referenced port.

Could someone please help me with this?

Here are code snippets from my `server.cpp` and `client.cpp` files.

server.cpp:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <errno.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   //Defining variables
    int my_socket, new_socket, c,error,bind_number;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char* message;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];// Client's remote name
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];// service i.e port the client is connected on
    WSADATA wsdata;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsok = WSAStartup(ver, &wsdata);
    PCWSTR client_IP_Addr=L"192.168.0.102";
    char connect[] = "connected on port";
    // initialize winsock
    if (wsok != 0)
        printf( "can't Initialize winsock! Quitting...\n");
    else
        printf("winsock successfully initialized !\n");

    //Create socket
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (my_socket == -1) printf("Could not create socket");

    //Geting client ip adress and port 
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = InetPton(AF_INET,client_IP_Addr, &server.sin_addr); //inet_addr("192.168.0.1");//client_ip
    server.sin_port = htons(4024);// not sure 

    //Bind
    bind_number = bind(my_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
    if (bind_number < 0) 
        //puts("bind failed due to error");
        perror("bind failed due to error:");
    return 1;
    puts("bind done");
...
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") 


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // ********************************************************
    // Defining the variables
    // ********************************************************
    WSADATA win32_initialisation;
    int error, caracter_lenght;
    char message[65535];
    char server_reply[65535];
    SOCKET my_socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN destination_information;
    PCWSTR server_IP_Addr =L"0.0.0.0";
    printf("\nHello, it's the client talking here\n");

    // ********************************************************
    // Winsock  Initialisation
    // ********************************************************
    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &win32_initialisation);
    if (error != 0)
        printf("\nSorry, can't initialise Winsock due to error : %d %d", error, WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nWSAStartup  : OK");

    // ********************************************************
    // Opening Socket
    // ********************************************************
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (my_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("\nSorry, can't create the socket due to error : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nsocket      : OK");

    // ********************************************************
    // Establishing session opening
    // ********************************************************
    destination_information.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destination_information.sin_addr.s_addr = InetPton(AF_INET, server_IP_Addr, &destination_information.sin_addr);
    destination_information.sin_port = htons(22); // Try 631 and 5900 if 22 isn't working
    error = connect(my_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&destination_information, sizeof(destination_information));
    if (error != 0)
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't open the TCP session due to error : %d %d", error, WSAGetLastError());
    else
        printf("\nsetsockopt  : OK");
...
```

Comment: Nothing C++ in this code and a lot of C stuff you wouldn't use in C++ so changing tags. Also tagging windows.

Comment: Your server socket must be bound to an ip local to the server on which the client will connect to. So the line `server.sin_addr.s_addr = InetPton(AF_INET,client_IP_Addr, &server.sin_addr);` is wrong

Comment: Moreover, your server listen on port `4024` ( `server.sin_port = htons(4024);// not sure` ), so your client must try to connect on that port, not 22, 631 or 5900.

Comment: And [InetPton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inetptonw) doesn't return what you want.

Comment: Using `0.0.0.0` as where to connect from the client looks unusual.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, there are a lot of problems in both sets of code, namely your use of IP addresses and ports are all wrong.

Also, your error handling is inadequate.  And in one place, it is even broken.  In the server code, if `bind()` fails, you are calling `perror()` to output the error (ok) but then it is followed by a `return` statement that is executed *unconditionally* regardless of whether `bind()` succeeded or failed, thus exiting the process.  The `if` block that calls `perror()` needs curly braces added, and then the `return` statement moved inside the braces.

```
//Bind
bind_number = bind(my_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
if (bind_number < 0) { // <-- add
    //puts("bind failed due to error");
    perror("bind failed due to error:");
    return 1; // <-- moved here!
} // <-- add
```

With that said, try something more like the following:

server.cpp:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h> 

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    //Defining variables
    SOCKET my_socket, new_socket;
    int error;
    SOCKADDR_IN server, client;
    std::string server_IP_Addr = "0.0.0.0";//"192.168.0.102"
    ...

    // initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsdata;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    error = WSAStartup(ver, &wsdata);
    if (error != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Sorry, can't initialize Winsock due to error : " << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Winsock successfully initialized!\n";
    
    //Create socket
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (my_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Sorry, Could not create socket due to error : " << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, server_IP_Addr.c_str(), &server.sin_addr);
    server.sin_port = htons(4024);

    //Bind
    if (bind(my_socket, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Sorry, Could not bind socket due to error : " << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        closesocket(my_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Bind successful!\n";

    ...
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h> 

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") 

int main()
{
    // ********************************************************
    // Defining the variables
    // ********************************************************
    WSADATA win32_initialisation;
    int error;
    SOCKET my_socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN destination_information;
    std::string server_IP_Addr = "192.168.0.102";
    ...

    std::cout << "Hello, it's the client talking here\n";

    // ********************************************************
    // Winsock  Initialisation
    // ********************************************************
    error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &win32_initialisation);
    if (error != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Sorry, can't initialize Winsock due to error : " << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "WSAStartup  : OK\n";

    // ********************************************************
    // Opening Socket
    // ********************************************************
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (my_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Sorry, can't create the socket due to error : " << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "socket      : OK\n";

    // ********************************************************
    // Establishing session opening
    // ********************************************************
    memset(&destination_information, 0, sizeof(destination_information));
    destination_information.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, server_IP_Addr.c_str(), &destination_information.sin_addr);
    destination_information.sin_port = htons(4024);

    error = connect(my_socket, (sockaddr*)&destination_information, sizeof(destination_information));
    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cerr << "Sorry, couldn't open the TCP session due to error : " << error << "! Quitting...\n";
        closesocket(my_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "connect  : OK\n";

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers.

Comment: I tried what you suggested me to do @Remy Lebeau. The thing is that I have no errors displayed on the terminal screen but instead, for the client's file the only message to be displayed is "Hello, it's the client talking here" and for the server's client file, it just ends with "Exit C:\Users\WFGP2\source\...\TCP_IP_Client_Code_NewVersion\Debu\TCP_IP_Client_Code_NewVersion.exe (processus 12952). Code: 1." Also as I'm trying to connect my computer to my raspberry I thought that using port 22 (ssh) could work. Is this why I'm having nothing display on my screen

Comment: Your client is exiting with error 1, which is `return 1` in the code. There should be an error message printed with it (if `cerr` doesn't work for you, use `cout` instead), but you need to debug your code to find which error (I'm guessing it is `connect()` trying to reach a wrong IP/port). Or change the `return`s to use different values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Remy Lebeau, it appears finally that the reason why nothing was printed on my screen lies in the fact that the "if" statements were not followed by curled brackets. As for "cerr" or "cout" they work perfectly well !

Comment: @PradWandji ok, good to know, I have updated my answer to include that.